# Connect SymmetricDS to an Existing H2 Databse File

Tags: java, database, h2, symmetricds

I've a H2 database file which I need to replicate using [SymmetricDS](http://www.symmetricds.org/).

I can access the database from web console in embedded mode using this url:

```
jdbc:h2:file:E:/Folder/database;AUTO_SERVER=TRUE;IFEXISTS=TRUE;
```

But using the same url in node properties file of symmtericds throws following error:

```
ERROR [server-000] [AbstractSymmetricEngine] [symmetric-engine-startup-0] Could not get a connection to the database: Cannot create PoolableConnectionFactory (IO Exception: "E:/Folder/database outside D:/symmetric-server-3.7.26/tmp/h2" [90028-182]).  Waiting for 10 seconds before trying to connect to the database again.
```

Though if the following url is used in the node properties file of symmetricds, everything works fine but the database is created in symmetric-server-3.7.26/tmp/h2 directory.

```
jdbc:h2:file:database;AUTO_SERVER=TRUE;
```

I've not had any luck in solving this issue in past couple of days.

Any kind of help will be greatly appreciated.

Going through H2 documentation I found out that the this behaviour is due to -baseDir option: http://www.h2database.com/html/advanced.html#remote_access .

But how is this option being set automatically and how to disable it..?

Doing some extensive research on the issue, root cause turns out to be the static block of *AbstractCommandLauncher* class of [SymmetricDS](http://www.symmetricds.org/):

```
static {
    String symHome = System.getenv("SYM_HOME");
    if (symHome == null) {
        symHome = ".";
    }
    System.setProperty("log4j.sym.home", symHome);
    if (isBlank(System.getProperty("h2.baseDir"))) {
       System.setProperty("h2.baseDir", symHome + "/tmp/h2");
    }
    DEFAULT_SERVER_PROPERTIES = System.getProperty(SystemConstants.SYSPROP_SERVER_PROPERTIES_PATH, symHome + "/conf/symmetric-server.properties");
    log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(AbstractCommandLauncher.class);
    initFromServerProperties();
}
```

And as it turns out, source code of [SymmetricDS](http://www.symmetricds.org/) will have to be modified to resolve it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SymmetricDS not connecting to H2 Database](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33967836/symmetricds-not-connecting-to-h2-database)

Comment: Not just "possible" to be precise, this is the very same question asked yesterday by the same user.

Comment: But I was advised to move the issue to a new question!

Comment: I have no ide who adviced you to do and exactly what, but reposting the very same question was surely wrong. That is just wasting people's time trying to ask for and figure out details that you may have already discussed in comments below the original one. Now that you have *deleted* the other question, it just got worse.

Comment: I'm just trying to get some help. And if you had read the comments on previous question, you'd definitely know why this question was put-up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This behaviour can not be disabled altogether but overriding it is possible by setting -Dh2.baseDir while running SymmetricDS. The original answer is [here](http://sourceforge.net/p/symmetricds/discussion/739237/thread/33c8a23b/)